# Group by month - Google bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a google bar chart here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jeag1gva/1/

What I want to do is group the costs for each month, so the chart would be:

January: Sum of all costs in january,
Februray: Sum of all costs in february
.. you get the idea

I figured the query:

```
query.setQuery("select A, sum(C) group by A ");
```

would add up all the numbers in C the C column, and return them, but that doesn't work.

I haven't had any luck with formatters either.

Has anyone done this before?

The resulting chart would look something similar to this: [image]

except it'd only have one bar on the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the query to `query.setQuery("select min(A), sum(C) group by month(A)");` aggregates the costs per month.

The formatter seems to be being applied. What's the issue you're seeing with it?